# How to show rows into column for same id in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show rows into column for specific id and make a flat table.

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

Here top two column are same patient. But their followup are different.

Now I want to show them in separate column instead row.

Comment: Click on table data

Comment: What is the other column?

Comment: like PatientID, Followup1, Followup2,... FollowupN etc?

Comment: Other columns are always null.

Comment: You're right @Harsh

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will help.

This is I am taking as schema:

```
declare @mytable as table(PateintID int, Followup Varchar(50));
Declare @FollowUps      VARCHAR(1000);

insert into @mytable values
(1, 'Follow up 1'),
(1, 'Follow up 2'),
(1, 'Follow up 3'),
(2, 'Follow up 1'),
(2, 'Follow up 2'),
(2, 'Follow up 2'),
(2, 'Follow up 3'),
(3, 'Follow up 1'),
(3, 'Follow up 2'),
(3, 'Follow up 3'),
(4, 'Follow up 1'),
(4, 'Follow up 2'),
(4, 'Follow up 2'),
(5, 'Follow up 1'),
(5, 'Follow up 2'),
(5, 'Follow up 3');
```

And Here is the query to bring the output:

```
SELECT PateintID,  Followup = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + Followup 
              FROM @mytable t1
              WHERE t1.PateintID = t2.PateintID
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') from @mytable t2
group by PateintID;
```

Above query will group all follow up grouping them to form a Comma separated list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create table #temp
(
ID int,
LabId varchar(20),
PatientId varchar(20),
TestName varchar(20),
SampleType varchar(20),
CollectionDate Date,
Followup varchar(20),
AFBResult Varchar(20),
GXMTB Varchar(20),
GXRIF Varchar(20),
CultureResult Varchar(20),
PCRResult Varchar(20),
QFTAgTB1 Varchar(20),
QFTAgTB2 Varchar(20),
QFTResult Varchar(20),
LPAMTC Varchar(20)
)

Insert into #temp values (2, 'AM-5000/18', '205181000001-9', 'AFB Microscopy', 'Urine', '2018-10-01', '1st Follow up', 
'Positive', Null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
Insert into #temp values (3, 'AM-5000/18', '205181000001-9', 'AFB Microscopy', 'Urine', '2018-10-01', '3rd Follow up', 
'Negative', Null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
Insert into #temp values (4, 'AM-5000/18', '201181000026-0', 'AFB Microscopy', 'Sputum', '2018-10-02', '', 
'Negative', Null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
Insert into #temp values (5, 'AM-5125/18', '201181000014-6', 'AFB Microscopy', 'Sputum', '2018-10-02', '', 
'Negative', Null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
Insert into #temp values (6, 'AM-5126/18', '201181000022-9', 'AFB Microscopy', 'Sputum', '2018-10-02', '', 
'Negative', Null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
Insert into #temp values (7, 'AM-5127/18', '201181000022-9', 'AFB Microscopy', 'Sputum', '2018-10-02', '1st Follow up', 
'Negative', Null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)

select PatientId, TestName, SampleType, [1st Follow up], [3rd Follow up]
from
(
  select  PatientId, TestName, SampleType, CollectionDate, Followup
  from #temp where PatientId = '205181000001-9' 
) d
pivot
(
  max(CollectionDate)
  for Followup in ([1st Follow up], [3rd Follow up])
) piv;

--select * from #temp
drop table #temp
```

Output is as shown below

```
PatientId       TestName        SampleType  1st Follow up   3rd Follow up
205181000001-9  AFB Microscopy  Urine       2018-10-01      2018-10-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go and look at the [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) keyword.